# Coordinate Link and Pressable in ReactNative

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I want my app to go to a specific route as well as changing the color of the Icon when I press it. However it only does one of them!

If I wrap  with  the color will change when I press. If I do the opposite, my app will navigate to the specified route.

I have tried to use other tags like Touchable, TouchableOpacity, etc.

This is my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Dimensions, Touchable, Pressable, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-      
native';
import { Link } from 'react-router-native';
import { Text } from 'react-native-paper';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
import { CommonActions } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native-web';

export default function BottomBar( ) {

const [focused, setFocused] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
debugger;
console.log(focused);
}, [focused])

const tabColor = (tabIndex) => {
return focused === tabIndex ? '#F29C46' : 'white';
};
return(
<View style={styles.container}>
  <Pressable  onPress={() => setFocused(1)}>
    <View style={styles.tab}>
    <Icon name="movie-open" size={25} color={tabColor(1)}/>
    <Text style={[{color : focused === 1?'#F29C46' : 'white'}, styles.labelText]}>Escenas</Text>
    </View>
  </Pressable>
    <Link to={{pathname: '/settings'}}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setFocused(2)}>
      <View style={styles.tab}>
      <Icon name="account-group" size={25} color={tabColor(2)}/>
      <Text style={[{color : focused === 2?'#F29C46' : 'white'},
 styles.labelText]}>Comunidad</Text>
      </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </Link>
  <Pressable onPress={() => setFocused(3)}>
    <View style={styles.tab}>
    <Icon name="account" size={25} color={tabColor(3)}/>
    <Text style={[{color : focused === 3?'#F29C46' : 'white'}, styles.labelText]}>Perfil</Text>
    </View>
  </Pressable>
  <Pressable onPress={() => setFocused(4)}>
    <View style={styles.tab}>
    <Icon name="cog" size={25} color={tabColor(4)}/>
    <Text style={[{color : focused === 4?'#F29C46' : 'white'}, styles.labelText]}>Ajustes</Text>
    </View>
  </Pressable>
</View>
);

}


const {width, height} = Dimensions.get('window')


//Style
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
position: 'absolute',
bottom: 0,
left: 0,
right: 0,
flexDirection: 'row',
justifyContent: 'space-around',
alignItems: 'center',
height: height*0.15,
width: width,
backgroundColor: '#303747',
},
labelText: {
fontSize: 15,
},
tab: {
alignItems: 'center',
}
});
```

Any help or guideline I would appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The [Pressable](https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressable) component from react native has [onPressIn](https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressable#onpressin) and [onPressOut](https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressable#onpressout) methods.

onPressIn can handle the style changes, it is triggered when a user first touches the component

onPressOut can handle navigation, this method is triggered the moment the user lifts their finger off the component.

The combination of these two methods should give you the desired outcome.

**Note:** I suggest creating a custom react component that returns a Pressable component which wraps your item's view; this will make handling state much easier per component. You can even reuse that component for all similar use cases and make it dynamic using props.